# How To Prevent GET Requests?

Tags: get, spam

I am creating a site that will encourage users to visit again. Therefore, I'm afraid of people sending spam or bots to the site.

How can I block this type of spam? I've heard of spamming GET requests to make it look like there are more visits. What can I do to protect myself?

Comment: you could set up a blacklist for your server so that if an IP address makes too many requests in a certain period of time, all their subsequent requests will bounce. however, this will not protect against a full scale DDoS attack (though not much will). are you expecting people to try to take down your site?

Comment: no, it wouldn't be a malicious attack to take the site down. There is a prize when it hits 100,000 visits (one per IP address per day), so I'm afraid of people trying to increase the number of hits unnaturally.

Answer (score 1):

The main way to cut down on bot artificial traffic is to use a "captcha" image

look into reCaptcha or secureimage and integrate this.  Whether you submit these methods via GET or POST, the captcha var will be checked on the server side at which point you can admit/deny for the purposes of averting bots.

Hope this helps.

R

Comment: something like a 'click here to count your visit' once a day. and once that happens they will see the number behind it. I would prefer something other than a traditional captcha, I can't imagine people being willing to do that just to count their visit

Comment: Daniel, perhaps only throw the captcha in there after a certain number of hits from a given IP address....in this way it wouldn't hit most users, but would slow down a bot to the point of not making it worthwhile to circumvent.

Comment: kinda like an increasing wait time between password retries on many authentication systems...

Comment: this might work depending on the specific question, if he wants to protect a specific URL from GET requests, then it will work. otherwise, you're just making it go to a different page when a GET request occurs